# Automating Google Maps in C# Web Browser (issue executing javascript properly)

Tags: c#, javascript, html, google-maps, automation

**NOT** using API

I am currently attempting to use a web browser in C# to load google maps and automatically focus on my current location, however, for some reason I cannot get this to work properly. The idea is simple. Load Google maps, and either execute the script to focus on my current location:

```
mapBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("mylocation.onButtonClick");
```

Or, invoke the button click through an HtmlElement:

```
HtmlElement myLocationButton = mapBrowser.Document.GetElementById("mylocation");
myLocationButton.InvokeMember("click");
```

But, of course neither of these methods actually work correctly, the coordinates returned are incorrent and the map never actually focuses. Any ideas on how I can fix this issue properly? The scripts aren't invoked until after the document is actually loaded:

```
private void mapBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(mapBrowser.Url.ToString() == "https://www.google.com/maps/preview/")
        {
            try
            {
                //HtmlElement myLocationButton = mapBrowser.Document.GetElementById("mylocation");
                //myLocationButton.InvokeMember("click");
                mapBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("mylocation.onButtonClick");
                //mapBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("focus:mylocation.main");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Invoking Script: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

so I don't believe that is the cause of my problem. Even more frustratingly, the auto-focus works fine if I click the button manually.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

(NOTE, you may have to go into IE and allow Google maps access to your location in order to replicate this issue properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had problem few times that WebBrowser control uses too old version of IE. You need to modify registry to get it to use newer version of IE.
I tried "https://www.google.com/maps/preview/" with both IE 8 and 9 and it gave me an error, but it works on IE 10.

See: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

Comment: Tried this, wrote some code in at the beginning to add a key for the app, however the program still doesn't execute the script (or maybe it does and the script just does nothing) either way it's still not functioning. No idea what's causing this.