# Unsupported browser in visual studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, google-maps, web, webbrowser-control

I want to display GPS coordinates on Google Maps. For this purpose I chose web browser from the toolbox. But it show an error of unsupported browser. I tried updating my Internet Explorer.

I also set Google Chrome as the Debugging Browser in Visual Studio but it didn't work.

This is the part of code where I am accessing the web browser.

```
try
{
    StringBuilder queryaddress = new StringBuilder();

    queryaddress.Append("https://maps.google.com/maps?q=");

    if (lat != string.Empty)
    {
        queryaddress.Append(lat + "," + "+");
    }

    webBrowser1.Navigate(queryaddress.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
}
```

**Error**

> You seem to be using an unsupported browser. Old browsers can put your
>   security at risk, are slow and don't work with newer Google Maps
>   features. To access Google Maps, you'll need to update to a modern
>   browser.

What is the best way to do this.?

Comment: Check this question, probably this is the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256997/automating-google-maps-in-c-sharp-web-browser-issue-executing-javascript-proper

Comment: I checked it out but it is not related to this problem. The only issue here is to loading the browser properly using visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this message since the [`WebBrowser` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) is emulating an older version of Internet Explorer on your machine:

> By default, this feature is enabled for Windows Internet Explorer and
>   for applications hosting the `WebBrowser` Control. To disable this
>   feature by using the registry, add the name of your executable file to
>   the following setting.

This can be changed via Registry settings:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
   SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Internet Explorer
            Main
               FeatureControl
                  FEATURE_BEHAVIORS
                     contoso.exe = (DWORD) <VALUE>
```

where `VALUE` is

- `11001 (0x2AF9)` Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11
  edge mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. Failing to
  declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks.
- `11000 (0x2AF8)` IE11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE
  directives are displayed in IE11 edge mode. Default value for IE11.
- `10001 (0x2711)` Internet Explorer 10. Webpages are displayed in IE10
  Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
- `10000 (0x02710)`    Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing
  standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards
  mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 10.
- `9999 (0x270F)`  Windows Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in
  IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive.
  Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in
  Quirks.
- `9000 (0x2328)`  Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing
  standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.
  Default value for Internet Explorer 9. Important  In Internet
  Explorer 10, Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives
  are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
- `8888 (0x22B8)`  Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode,
  regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. Failing to declare a
  !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks.
- `8000 (0x1F40)`  Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives
  are displayed in IE8 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 8
  Important  In Internet Explorer 10, Webpages containing
  standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards
  mode.
- `7000 (0x1B58)`  Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives
  are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. Default value for applications
  hosting the WebBrowser Control.

Follow [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation) for a more details.

Comment: I added the executable file name in registry. But it didn't worked

Comment: Try also to add registry using this path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`. It is valid for 32 bit apps running on 64 bit machine [source](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)

Comment: I tried doing this but this time also it is not working. I am sharing the picture of what I have done. 
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1241569925869619&set=a.168862533140369.44503.100000498692181&type=3&theater

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1241574285869183&set=a.168862533140369.44503.100000498692181&type=3&theater

Comment: From your last   screenshot, it should be name of executable file,`Read_Excel_Files.exe` instead of `Read_Excel_Files`

Comment: I changed the name with .exe extension but still the problem is same.