# Google map integration problem: you seem to be using an unsupported browser

Tags: google-maps

When we want to integrate Google map in windows application by using C# it gives the following errors when we run the application

> error : you seem to be using an unsupported browser

Comment: Use a supported browser.

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/qjPThkU5rDs), it seems that there is/are one or more addons or extension which is not allowing map to load. You can try to check one by one. Maybe it updated and broke maps.

You can also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493945/unsupported-browser-in-visual-studio-2010-c-sharp) which states that maybe the [WebBrowser control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) is emulating an older version of Internet Explorer on your machine.

> By default, this feature is enabled for Windows Internet Explorer and for applications hosting the `WebBrowser` Control. To disable this feature by using the registry, add the name of your executable file to the following setting.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a different web browser embedded control. For example, you can look at Chromium Embedded Framework.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework

I believe it should work pretty well. According to the documentation this framework embeds a Chromium browser (open-source web browser closely related to the Google Chrome browser) which uses the modern HTML5 and V8 JavaScript engine.